# Groovy 2d arrays

Tags: groovy, multidimensional-array

I have 3 arrays, `l1[,,,,], l2[,,,,] and l3[,,,,]`. Each of which has 5 characters in it.

```
e.g. l1["A","B","C","D","E"]
```

The 2d array is made up of these

```
screen = [l1[],l2[],l3[]]
```

so it will look as so:

```
screen = [[,,,,],[,,,,],[,,,,]]
```

How can I iterate through this array?

do I call `screen[5]`? or `screen[l1[5]]`?

can I:

```
for (i in 1..15){

 println screen[i]
}
```

please help!!!

How can I iterate in the array and call different parts, e.g. the `1st element` of each sub array?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So, given:

```
List l1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
List l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
List l3 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

List screen = [ l1, l2, l3 ]
```

To iterate all the elements, you could do:

```
3.times { y ->
    5.times { x ->
        println screen[ y ][ x ]  
    }
}
```

Or, you could use `mod` and `intdiv` to work out x and y positions:

```
15.times { p ->
    def x = p % 5
    def y = p.intdiv( 5 )
    println screen[ y ][ x ]
}
```

Or, if you want the first element from each sub-list, you can do:

```
println screen*.head()
```

Or, say you want the 3rd element from each sub-list:

```
println screen*.getAt( 2 )
```

Alternatively, you could put all the items into a one-dimensional List:

```
def inlineScreen = [ *l1, *l2, *l3 ]
```

Then access then by:

```
15.times { p ->
    println inlineScreen[ p ]
}
```

or:

```
def x = 1, y = 1
println inlineScreen[ x + y * 5 ]
```

Or, if it is important that you always want to get the elements together (ie, you always want the second elements from all the arrays together), then you could do:

```
// groupedScreen == [['A', 'a', '1'], ['B', 'b', '2'], ['C', 'c', '3'], ['D', 'd', '4'], ['E', 'e', '5']]
def groupedScreen = [ l1, l2, l3 ].transpose()
```

Then, to get the 3rd elements, you can just do:

```
groupedScreen[ 2 ]
```