# how to add an array to an array, (index location to index location?) to make a multidimensional array in Groovy script

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, groovy, soapui

I have two sets of data in two separate lists (I'm using soapui open groovy script) - which has gone through `XmlSlurper().parseText()` not sure if this matters

```
a = [c1,c2,c3] 
b = [0 100, 0 50 100, 0 500 1000]
```

and I want to combine them (location 0 to location 0 then location 1 to location 1 etc)  to be like this

```
c = [[c1,0 100],[c2,0 50 100],[c3,0 500 100]]
```

The code I have so far

```
def splitList(list, splitAt) 
{
    list.inject([]) { curr, val ->
    if(curr.size() == 0 || val == splitAt) 
    {
        curr << []
    }
        curr[-1] << val
        curr
    }
}

def c = [a, splitList(b, 0)].transpose()*.flatten()
```

and when I `log.info c` I get `[[c1,0 100, 0 50 100, 0 500 100]]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Groovy 2d arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986506/groovy-2d-arrays)

Comment: So does a new sequence in `b` always start with 0?

Comment: @tim_yates yes, `b` will always start with 0 and the size of that list might be only two (0,100), 3(0,100,100) or more

Comment: @Sega-Zero are you talking about `transpose`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this...

```
count = 0
c = a.collect {
    [it, b[count++]]
}
```

That code skips any error handling and just assumes that `a` and `b` have the same number of elements.

Comment: Isn't that just `transpose `?

Comment: I couldn't get `transpose` to work as efficiently as that code.

Comment: `transpose` added everything in `b` to the index location `0` of `a` then index location `1` of `a` and so on and so on. Instead i needed to add everything at index `0` of `b` into index `0` of `a` then add index `1` of b into `1` of `a`

Comment: So your data is not like you say in the question?

Comment: @tim_yates Yes, I think you could also do something like `c = [a, b].transpose()`.  I think there are a lot of ways to get there.

Comment: @tim_yates In my question i say I wanted the data like this `c = [[c1,0 100],[c2,0 50 100],[c3,0 500 100]]`. I;m not sure where the confusion is?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I'm not very good with this, I just tried your very simple way and it worked haha.... thanks I'd rather use this way and don't know why it wasn't working for me earlier - my apologies

Comment: @MistaWizard - I am glad you got it working.  I didn't show the `transpose` solution because I thought you were trying to avoid that.  Apparently I misunderstood.  In any case, glad you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

So, given your two lists:

```
def a = ['c1','c2','c3']
def b = [0, 100, 0, 50, 100, 0, 500, 1000]
```

You can define a function that splits a list every time it sees a given value:

```
def splitList(list, splitAt) {
    list.inject([]) { curr, val ->
        if(curr.size() == 0 || val == splitAt) {
            curr << []
        }
        curr[-1] << val
        curr
    }
}
```

So calling `splitList(b, 0)` returns `[[0, 100], [0, 50, 100], [0, 500, 1000]]`

And then use this (and `transpose` and `flatten`) to get:

```
def c = [a, splitList(b, 0)].transpose()*.flatten()
```

So that:

```
assert c == [['c1', 0, 100], ['c2', 0, 50, 100], ['c3', 0, 500, 1000]]
```

Comment: Thanks tim_yates, i think i see how this works and I'm playing with it now. I've come across this `>>` before - could you explain what this does and `->`?

Comment: `->` separates the parameters from the implementation for a closure. `<<` is the left-shift operator and where the left hand side us a list, it appends an element to the list

Comment: Thanks for the edit, helped clean up an index issue :) this only added all of `b` to only the first of `a` tho so i lost all the `c2` and `c3`

Comment: Maybe if you edit your question so it's the same as your problem, we can find a solution for your real problem?